# How to present ModalViewController in iOS app with TabBarController?

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, uiwindow

I am looking for feedback on a best practice approach when you want to present a LoginViewController as a "ModalViewController" in an app with TabBarController.

The case is this:
 - Application supports user sessions with login/logout functionality 
 - When the app is launched it tries to login automaticly and either display TabBarController directly or the LoginViewController (displayed as a ModalViewController to enable a dismiss animation on login)
 - The application has a TabBarController with a number of tabs.
 - Each time a ViewController is presented the user's state is checked
 - If the user isn't logged in a ModalViewController with login functionality should be presented
 - If the user manually logout the same ModalViewController should be presented

I have tried to come up with several different designs to handle this and no one feels completely "correct". I have worked on one project where this was handled using a subclassed UIWindow which replaced the apps default UIWindow. The subclass then listened for different Notifications such as "UserLoggedInSuccessfully", "UserLoggedOut" etc, to handle presentation of the ModalViewController.

Are there any other solutions to this? I would appreciate any input and experiences of this kind of solution.

Comment: Why check if the user is logged in when you switch tabs? If it's required to be logged in to use the app, then just login at startup. When the app is exited (or goes into the background if you want), you can log the user out automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I guess a check when switching tab isn't needed since it will be handled on all API-requests anyways. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

There are different solutions for this problem , you could try these alternatives but first one is the recommended approach I would say,

1. You can make your `HomeViewController` which will be first tab of `TabBarController` as default to open every time, and make the `LoginViewController` separately, in your AppDelegate you could check  the login session in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and if the session is not valid then show the `LoginViewController` as `ModalViewController` otherwise show the `TabBarController` with all the tabs included.
2. Alternative could be to have all the Controllers in The Tab but when you present `LoginViewController` , after user has signed in, add all the controllers in a `MutbaleArray` and delete the current object which is `LoginViewController`. Once user is signed in , save the info in the keychain and this way user will not have to login again and again, this way you can avoid showing the `LoginViewController` every time, once user tries to log out , then add the `LoginViewController` in an Array and then add all the `TabBarController` objects after `LoginViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You may to do the following ,
when user open the app you have to show hime the loginviewcontroller as the rootviewcontroller then when login successfully you have to make the tabbarviewcontroller as the rootViewcontroller .
then each time when the user run the app you have to check if he has a valid session you will make a tabar as a root
if the the session expire when you on the tabbar , you have to change the root view controller from your app delegate to sign in